JdbcIsolationDelegate related exception while starting springboot app
I have migrated my spring boot app from springboot 2.7.18 to 3.3.1. Java version is 21.
'mvn clean install' runs fine, but when I launch app('mvn spring-boot:run'), I see error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException,
String)" because the return value of
"org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()"
is null

Google search hasn't hepled me much.
Any lead on it?
